# redux-observable use RxJS to emit progress actions for ajax call

Tags: redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I have been wrestling with this problem and feel like I have a fundamental misunderstanding. I am using the `redux-observable` library in `React` which glues `redux` together with `RxJS` for handling asynchrony. My problem is that I have to handle a large upload and I want to show progress as the file is loaded.

The function `uploadFileEpic` needs to return an `Observable<Action>` to work with `redux-observable`. The `uploadObservable` represents the workflow that I want to accomplish. If I just return the `uploadObservable` the upload works but I don't get any `handleUploadFileProgress` actions from the `progressSubscriber` in the `ajax` call. Ideally the `progressSubscriber` would be adding elements to another observable that I could merge with `uploadObservable`. You see me trying to use `merge` here but the TypeScript compiler complains saying the return is not assignable to an `ObservableInput`.

I keep going in circles so I feel my understanding must be fundamentally off. I feel like I'm missing some simple `RxJS` magic here. Thanks for the help!

```
import { Observable, Observer, Subscriber, Subject, of } from 'rxjs';
import { ajax } from 'rxjs/ajax';
import { ofType } from 'redux-observable';
import { catchError, delay, map, mergeMap, tap, merge } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { apis } from '../../config';

export const enum ActionType {
  InitialFileUpload
  FileProgress
  UploadFileSuccess
  UploadFileFail
}

const handleInitialFileUpload = (file: File, timeLimit: number) => ({
  type: ActionType.InitialFileUpload,
  file,
  timeLimit
})

const handleFileProgress = (file: File, percentComplete: number) => ({
  type: ActionType.FileProgress,
  file,
  percentComplete
})

const handleUploadFileSuccess = (file: File, timeLimit: number) => ({
  type: ActionType.UploadFileSuccess,
  file,
  timeLimit
})

const handleUploadFileFail = (file: File, timeLimit: number) => ({
  type: ActionType.UploadFileFail,
  file,
  timeLimit
})


export const uploadFileEpic= action$ =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType(ActionType.InitialFileUpload),
    mergeMap((action: any) => {
      const { file, timeLimit } = action;
      const data = new FormData()
      data.append('importFile', file, file.name)
      data.append('timeLimit', timeLimit)
      const progressSubject = new Subject();

      const ajaxRequest = {
        url: apis.gateway.run,
        method: 'POST',
        body: data,
        headers: {},
        progressSubscriber: Subscriber.create(
          (e: ProgressEvent) => {
            const percentComplete = Math.round((e.loaded / e.total) * 100)
            console.log("Progress event")
            progressSubject.next(handleUploadFileProgress(file, percentComplete))
          }
        )
      }

      const uploadObservable = ajax(ajaxRequest)
        .pipe(
          map(res => handleUploadFileSuccess(file)),
          delay(SUCCESSFUL_UPLOAD_NOTIFICATION_LENGTH),
          map(() => handleUploadFileRemove(file)),
          catchError(error => of(handleUploadFileFail(file, error.response)))
        )

      return merge(uploadObservable, progressSubject)
      }
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be importing `merge` from `rxjs/operators`. There, `merge` is treated as an operator and thus returning an `OperatorFunction`. By importing from simply `rxjs` you get the static merge that correctly returns an `Observable` which will be flattened by your `mergeMap`.